# How do I show the display value for a combo box for the bound item?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, windows-forms-designer, bindingsource

I have a windows forms combo box that isn't showing the display value for the current record.  The drop down list is showing the right values--Box, Skid, Tray--but the initial value in the text box is the ID; that is I'm seeing "3" instead of "Tray".  What am I missing?

Here are the values for the forms; each item has a container ID:

[image]

Here are the values for the combo box.  This links the chart above to a container:

[image]

The value shown in the combo box is the ID, not the container name.  This should show "Box, Box, Skid" but instead shows 3, 3, 2.

[image]

You can see the drop down list is populated correctly:

[image]

Here's how the combo box is created in the designer.  I also tried setting the selected value to the containerID from the dataset shown in the first image above, but I get the same results as leaving it blank.

[image]

Here's how the designer code looks:

[image]

Here's how the data sources are set:

[image]

Here's the query to get the combo box values:

[image]

Here's the query to get the item values:

[image]

ContainersModel class:
[image]

Comment: Try using a BindingList instead of a List.

Comment: Tried a BindingList and got the same results.  Thanks for the suggestion and let me know if you have any others.

Comment: What does your ContainersModel class look like?

Comment: I added it to the original question.  It has an int named containerID and a string named containerName.

Comment: Side note: pictures of code usually attract downvotes.  Always try to post code snippets as text.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by using the DataBindings in the property window for the combo box instead of setting them in the task window (using the arrow in the right hand corner of the combo box).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **ComboBox.SelectedValue** property for a data binding instead of the **Text** property. The **SelectedValue** property value is associated with the ValueMember field.