# How do I display a different list than the source item when opening the combo box?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding, datagrid

I'm using C# WPF with a SQL Server database. I have DataGrid that filled by `Factor` table from database (ItemSource).

Inside of this DataGrid, I have a combobox that is also filled with different table as `Commodity` that is related to `Factor`.

[image]

**What I need**

I want the combobox I have to be filled with a list from my `Commodity` table, but what is selected as the value is from the data grid (from the value filled in each row).

**What have I tried**

XAML:

```xml
    <Window x:Class="ComboDataWPF.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ComboDataWPF"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            x:Name="InvoiceWindow"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
        
        <Grid>
            <DataGrid x:Name="MainDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding WHOLE_DATA_FACTOR, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer Name" Width="120" Binding="{Binding CustomerName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />
    
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="The Product Customer Bought" Width="200">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox_Commodity"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=InvoiceWindow ,Path=TheCommodityCombo_DATA}"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="CommodityName"
                                          SelectedValuePath="CommodityCode"
                                          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                                          IsEditable="True"
                                          SelectedIndex="0"  BorderBrush="#FFADEEB4" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1">
                                    
                                    <!--For ComboBox_Commodity ↑-->
                                    <!--SelectedValue="{Binding The selected value of each combo box is proportional and based on the value of that row in the datagrid}"-->
                                    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    
                </DataGrid.Columns>
    
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Code-behind:

```cs
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        MyerEntities dbms = new MyerEntities();

        /// <summary>
        /// For Factor Table
        /// </summary>
        public class MyCustomModel_Factor
        {
            public long? NUMBER { get; set; }
            public string CustomerName { get; set; }
            public long? CommodityCode { get; set; }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<MyCustomModel_Factor> WHOLE_DATA_FACTOR { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyCustomModel_Factor>();
    
        /// <summary>
        /// For Commodity Table for ComboBox Items
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<MyCustomModel_Commodity> TheCommodityCombo_DATA { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyCustomModel_Commodity>();
        public class MyCustomModel_Commodity
        {
            public long CommodityCode { get; set; }
            public string CommodityName { get; set; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Filling DataGrid by ObservableCollection
            WHOLE_DATA_FACTOR.Clear();
            var RST = dbms.Database.SqlQuery<MyCustomModel_Factor>("SELECT * FROM Factor").ToList();
            foreach (var item in RST)
            { WHOLE_DATA_FACTOR.Add(item); }
    
            //Filling ComboBox from another table that is related to Factor table
            TheCommodityCombo_DATA.Clear();
            var RST2 = dbms.Database.SqlQuery<MyCustomModel_Commodity>("SELECT CommodityCode, CommodityName FROM dbo.Commodity").ToList();

            foreach (var item2 in RST2)
            {
                TheCommodityCombo_DATA.Add(item2);
            }
        }
    }
```

My source code: https://ufile.io/x4xqe9ti

Similar question but for Winforms:
[How do I show the display value for a combo box for the bound item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52374125/how-do-i-show-the-display-value-for-a-combo-box-for-the-bound-item)

How can I do that in WPF? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the binding to the collection of commodities to use a `RelativeSource`:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TheCommodityCombo_DATA, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
```

Then you should see the values to choose from in the `ComboBox`.

For the correct value to get selected, you should then bind the `SelectedValue` property of the `ComboBox` to the `CommodityCode` property of the model:

```
<ComboBox ... SelectedValue="{Binding CommodityCode}"
```

Comment: In case the MainWindow instance does not use itself as its DataContext (but instead a view model object), the more general form would be `{Binding Path=DataContext.TheCommodityCombo_DATA, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}`

Comment: Why WPF doesn't have a easy way for this stuff , you can do this what I need easily in MS Access VBA